# Connecting to Oracle12C database using standalone java client Vs Connecting through Websphere

Tags: websphere, oracle12c

Connection to Oracle 12c from a standalone java application succeeds when ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc5.jar is used.

Connection String : `jdbc:oracle:thin:@serverName:port:sid`

Whereas the same connection string fails when connecting through Websphere with the following exception.

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol 
>   DSRA0010E: SQL State = 99999, Error Code = 28,040

Note : Tried `ojdbc8.jar` and `ojdbc6.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol` error generally indicates that you are using an older JDBC driver with a newer database.  You should either update your JDBC driver so that it is the same version as the database or update your sqlnet.ora file with the appropriate `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER`/`SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT` values. See [Oracle's SQLNET documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF2010) for more information.

Note that if you think you are using the same version JDBC driver as the database it is possible that a different JDBC driver is being picked up in the WebSphere environment. If that is the case:

1. Check that there are no additional JDBC drivers packaged with your application.
2. Check if there are other Oracle JDBC Providers configured in WebSphere using an older JDBC driver. If so either modify your configuration so all of your providers are using the same version Oracle JDBC driver or you will need to [Isolate your JDBC Providers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21634612).

Comment: Thank You ! The issue was that i had 2 versions of JDBC drivers and had two data source providers each referring to one of the versions. Apparently the two versions of jdbc drivers in the classpath created the issue. I upgraded all the data sources to use ojdbc6.jar and it worked.